# Setting up DRBL for Clonezilla issue with instructions

Tags: clonezilla

I'm having trouble setting up [DRBL](http://drbl.org/about/) for Clonezilla.

The [instructions](http://drbl.org/installation/01-prepare-server.php) in step 1 say to uninstall the program used to access the internet then step 2 calls for using the program that was just uninstalled to access the internet. Step 2 specifically states that step 1 MUST be completed before moving to step 2.

I am expecting a response that either tells me what I am doing wrong or has a workaround for getting this set up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the instructions correctly, it does tell you to remove NetworkManager, but that doesn't mean you cannot use your network. Basically, you need to bring the ethernet interface down (`sudo ifdown eth0`), manually edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add static addresses, then bring the interface up again (`sudo ifup eth0`).